# Git branching model: a few questions

Tags: git, version-control, branching-strategy

We have almost settled for a branching model where we have a `master` branch which represents the production code and a `release-x.x` branch that represents future releases.

However, there are a few scenarios we are unsure how to solve effectively:

**Live bug fix is not relevant for the current release**

1. A new `feature` is branched of the `release-2.0` and does a complete re-write of module A.
2. The new `feature` is completed and merged in `release-2.0`.
3. A bug in the current live module A is found and fixed on `master`.

At this point we figured there are 2 possible scenarios:

1. We rebase `release-2.0` on `master` to bring bug fixes and fix conflicts (discarding the bug fix code which is now irrelevant). Eventually we then merge `release-2.0` in `master` when the release is ready.
2. We cherry-pick only the bug fixes that are relevant to the release into `release-2.0` and when the release is ready we override the entire `master` history with the `release-2.0` history.

Solution #1 forces us to resolve merge conflicts with commits we know aren't needed, but solution #2 forces us to wipe the entire `master` branch and replace it by the `release-2.0` branch's history on every release. That introduces a slight chance of losing bug fixes we forgot to cherry-pick on `release-2.0` and could also break ongoing bug fixes that were branched of `master` before the release.

**A feature doesn't make it into the release afterall**

1. We create a new `feature`, rebase on `release-2.0` and merge it into `release-2.0` with `--no-ff`.
2. A few bugs are found so we fix them on `feature` and redo the above merge process.
3. Clients review the feature once again a decides they wants to change many things -- the feature has no value without these things, but we cannot make these changes for the `release-2.0` and will have to wait until `release-3.0`.

What is the proper way to deal with that scenario? Should we revert all commits related to the feature that were done in `release-2.0` with a message such as "Revert feature X - pushed back to 3.0" and then later merge `feature` to `release-3.0`?

Comment: It seems like there are multiple questions here, both of which are primarily matters of opinion.  Is it possible to narrow the focus of the question and rephrase it as a technical issue?

Comment: @plalx have you get the answer to solve your questions? If yes, you can mark it as answer. And it will benefit others who have similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

**First**, if you changed module A both in `release-2.0` and `master` branch, and you want to apply the changes of module A on `master` to your `release-2.0` branch.

Except the solution1 and solution2 you listed, there is another way that you can only apply changes of module A from `master` to `release-2.0`. That is **checkout the related file(s) from `master` to `release-2.0` directly and then commit changes**. Detail steps as below:

```
git checkout release-2.0
git checkout master /path/to/moduleA  
# Such as git checkout master moduleA/*
# Now module A is what you changed in master
git commit
```

**Second**, for most cases, if you use the version format as `x.y` (major.minor), `x` (major)  stands for the main/significant changes required by clients, and `y` (minor) means we fix bugs or clients need little changes when they review the work you did.

So if your clients make requests for big changes when they review the version of 2.0, you can develop the project as version 3.0. After finishing works, your client will review the version of 3.0. If they report bugs or tiny changes for the version of 3.0, you can changes the version as 3.1 (rename your `release-3.0` branch as `release-3.1` or add tag 3.1 after you finish changes).

**Besides**, there is [another different branching module](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) you can refer: works on `develop` branch -> when finish the work -> merge `develop` into `release` branch -> after the `release` branch is approved/reviewed -> merge `release` into `master` branch -> record the release version in tag.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using tags instead of branches to represent what is in production. This way you could simply checkout a new hotfix branch and fix your bug, then deploy this commit directly and tag it as the current production code, no need to merge it back if you know that everything will change the next release.

```
* 54c82e0 - (HEAD -> master) Commit6
* bb6db8e - Commit5 
* 5156c9f - Commit4 
| * 630a150 - (tag: v1.1) Hotfix commit 
|/
* db5c984 - (tag: v1.0) Commit3 
* 00c6c5c - Commit2 
* 715412a - Commit1
```

You would use the branching model that you have planed, but master will instead be a your "trunk", where all your work is merged to, while the current production code will always have a tag, that you can checkout from if you need hotfixes.

I would be careful with choosing a "proven" branching model like GitFlow blindly, so I think you are on the right track, trying to find out what suits your needs. For more reading see:

- [Git Cooperation - From fancy to Functioning](https://kofoedanders.com/git-cooperation-simplified/)
- [GitFlow considered harmful](http://endoflineblog.com/gitflow-considered-harmful)
- [trunkbaseddevelopment.com](https://trunkbaseddevelopment.com/)

Comment: Well l'm actually trying to achieve trunk-based development, not GitFlow ;)

Comment: Sounds good! Though, release branches is in no way needed if you try to achieve a more fluid branching model. Trunkbased pretty much removes all excess branches, the exception being feature branches used for pull requests and code review etc.

Comment: Well in my case we need short-lived release branches only to prepare the release itself (e.g. we could have to remove some features that are in master but should only get deployed in a future release somehow -- things like that).